# Django admin, editing multiple models in the same line?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am using [django suit](https://github.com/darklow/django-suit) I am looking to do something like this:

[image]

I copied first "block" to the right(block in red). I would like to display data from different models there(Url1,Url2,Url3,Url4)... I know django suit provides widgets for this kind of thing but it would be a lot more convenient to have everything in the same screen.

I have no idea where to find examples about this and what direction to take. Tried googling but can't find any similar examples.

Any ideas?